# condition to run task with dependence

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In gitlab ci pipeline, I know how to set the dependency between stages.

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  needs: [iac]
  ...
```

I also know to set filter,

```
iac:
  stage: iac
  only:
    changes:
      - iac/*
  ...
```

But how to set the dependency and filter together. The conditions are:

stage `iac`: if any files under folder `iac` are changed, need run this stage, if no change, skip

stage `deploy`: depends on stage `iac` ,

But when stage `iac` is skipped (no change), the pipeline will be confused.

```
'deploy' job needs 'iac' job, but 'iac' is not in any previous stage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `deploy` stage is looking for `iac` stage evrytime, you need to apply the same rules to both stages. You can use the [rules keywords because](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except) :

> only and except are not being actively developed. rules is the
> preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines.

So you can define a global rule and extends it to the jobs you want to filter :

```
.rules:iac-changes:
  rules:
    - changes:
      - iac/*

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  extends:
    - .rules:iac-changes
  needs: [iac]
  ...

iac:
  stage: iac
  extends:
    - .rules:iac-changes
  ...
```

If you want to run the `deploy` stage anyway, you can make the [needs optional](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsoptional).

Comment: seems to set `optional: true` is the write way, let me try

Comment: confirmed, `optional: true` works as expect